# MDM VS Mobile Application Analytics

Tags: android, iphone, mdm

How can we use Mobile Device Management (MDM) Softwares?  Apple has provided the information in the [link](http://www.apple.com/ipad/business/integration/mdm/).

1. If both are same which one is the best?
2. How MDM is different from Mobile Analytics?
3. Is Event tracking is available in MDM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MDM is meant for organizations that want to be able to manage one or more (usually a lot more) mobile devices for a group of users. That includes installing software, setting up mail and other settings, configuring security policies, etc.

Analytics is something quite different -- usually it refers to a service that a particular application can use to measure the use of that application: how many times was the game played, when did the user click a button, etc.